# A question on a degenerate SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This may be a basic question of stochastic differential equation.

Let $U$ be the closed unit disk $U=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid |x|\le 1\}$, where $|\cdot|$ is the standard Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  We denote by $\partial U$ the boundary of $U$.

We consider a diffusion process $X=\{X(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ on $U$ such that
\begin{align*}
X(t)=x+\int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{1-|X(s)|^2}\,dB(s),\quad t \ge 0,
\end{align*}
where $x \in U$ and $B=\{B(t)\}_{t \ge 0}$ is a two-dimensional Brownian motion.

**My question**

If $x \in \partial U$, $X(t) \in \partial U$ for any $t \ge0$ ?

If $|x|=1$, the diffusion coefficient of $X$ vanishes. Therefore, it should follows that $X(t)=x$, $t \ge 0$. However, I could not reach this equality. A simple calculation yields that
\begin{align*}
E[|X(t)-x|^2]&=E\left[\int_{0}^{t}(1-|X(s)|^2),ds \right]=E\left[\int_{0}^{t}\left||X(s)|^2-|x|^2 \right|\,ds \right] \\
&\le 2 E\left[\int_{0}^{t}\left|X(s)-x \right|\,ds \right],\quad t \ge 0.
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, this is not enough to use the Gronwall inquality. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Why don't you try to calculate $\Bbb E[|X(t)|^2]$ instead of $\Bbb E[|X(t)-x|^2]?$ I think you'll get a nicer relation.

Comment: @Shalop Thank you for your comment. I feel that calculating $E[|X(t)|^2]$ is not very good. Can you show that $E[|X(t)|^2] \ge |x|^2$?

Comment: Note that $X(t)-x$ is a martingale starting from zero, therefore $\Bbb E[|X(t)|^2]$ should just be $|x|^2 + \Bbb E[|X(t)-x|^2]$ (the expectation of the cross term vanishes since it's a martingale started at zero). Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Shalop Oh, I see. Thank you for teaching me. We obtained that $E[|X(t)|^2] \ge 1$. So,  if $X(t) \notin \partial U$ with a positive probability, is it contradictory to being  $E[|X(t)|^2] \ge 1$?

Comment: @Shalop Thank you. I have proved that $X(t) \in \partial U$ for any $t \ge0$.